# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) but image shows up

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, directory-structure

**trying to to justify my content using flexbox and this code shows up:**
*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

The image does show up though. but the image does not move.

```
<div class="portrait-container">
      <div class="frame">
          <img class="portrait" alt="image" src="./image.png"/>
      </div>
</div>

.portrait-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

The image is in my folder too.

Answer (score 0):

Use **style** tag

```css
<style>
.portrait-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I don't want style tags in my html. I want to keep it in my css stylesheet

Comment: then put that part at css stylesheet